# How to catch unhandled exceptions in custom controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, exception, user-controls

Is there anything similar to the MyApplication_UnhandledException for an user control in VB?
I would like to have a central point where to catch all unhandled exceptions of a user control, without propagating the exception to the application that uses the user control.

I made some test raising an exception in a method of my user control where there is no try/catch code (of course in the true project all methods have a try/catch block).
The exception was caught by MyApplication_UnhandledException event of the application using the user control.
But this is too "far" from the point where the exception happens and in worst case the user should restart the application.

I would like to realize a behaviour for the user control in order that if the user control fails, the exception is not propagated till the application, but just caught at user control level.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Edit: I forgot to tell that I am talking about WinForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there really isn't. There is an [exception handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) for the forms threads, but this is also global (i.e. all forms participate).

Your only real option is to add appropriate try/catch blocks throughout.

Comment: Which would be the advantage of using Application.ThreadException event instead of MyApplication_UnhandledException event?

Comment: The biggest difference is that there is a chance that allowing the user to ignore the exception raised in the Windows Forms thread could allow the program to continue to run successfully. For example, if a developer forgot to add an exception handler to a button click event, the ThreadException could report the exception and ask the user if they want to continue. If they do, the exception would be ignored; if they don't the application could be terminated.

Comment: Well, if I understand, I shall prefer ThreadException at application level. Is it usual to use both ThreadException and MyApplication_UnhandledException in an Application?

Comment: We always hook ThreadException to give the user an opportunity to carry on (at their own risk) if the exception occurs in the winforms thread. And we have a framework that always hooks UnhandledException and handles it in a standard way, so for us it is common. If you don't want/need to give the user an opportunity to continue, it would be fine just to hook Unhandled.

Answer (score 0):

Is the InnerException of that Exception not null?  Sometimes it goes down a few levels, but you can recursively iterate until you find the inner-most InnerException and log that ErrorMessage & StackTrace.